# Automapper custom ValueResolver with dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map from a db-model to a view model. For one property I need a custom value resolver.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Model.Db.Kontoauszug, KontoauszugDetailViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IsTeamleiter, opt => opt.MapFrom<KontoauszugIsTeamleiterResolver>());
});

var mapper = new Mapper(config);

return mapper.Map<KontoauszugDetailViewModel>(kontoauszug);
```

The custom value resolver is dependent on a service as you can see here:

```
public class KontoauszugIsTeamleiterResolver : IValueResolver<Model.Db.Kontoauszug, KontoauszugDetailViewModel, bool>
{
    private readonly ISysParamService sysParamService;

    public KontoauszugIsTeamleiterResolver(ISysParamService sysParamService)
    {
        this.sysParamService = sysParamService;
    }

    public bool Resolve(Model.Db.Kontoauszug source, KontoauszugDetailViewModel destination, bool destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var teamleiter = this.sysParamService.GetParamValueAs<string>(KontoauszugSysParamConst.KONTOAUSZUG_TEAMLEITER_MANUMMERN).Split(";").ToList();
        return teamleiter.Contains(source.MitarbeiterNr);
    }
}
```

Unfortuantely, when running this code throws a exception that the valueresolver does not have a parameterless constructor.

I'm using the standard .net core dependency injection and in my Startup.cs I'm registering the automappers via

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

I've also tried to explicitly register the value resolver:

```
services.AddScoped<IValueResolver<Model.Db.Kontoauszug, KontoauszugDetailViewModel, bool>, KontoauszugIsTeamleiterResolver>();
```

But it does not work.

What am I doing wrong that this exception is thrown?

Thank in advance

Comment: MapFrom accept a resolver instance. You can retrieve the resolver from service provider and pass it like : `opt => opt.MapFrom(services.Get<IValueResolver<Model.Db.Kontoauszug, KontoauszugDetailViewModel, bool>>()`

Comment: hmm I'm setting up the mapper configuration in an extension method where I don't have access to IServiceCollection :(

Comment: Maybe you can inject the IServiceProvider in the extended class and expose it to the extension method.

Comment: You're supposed to use the value resolver in the mapping profile not in the service setup tho. an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833643/automapper-custom-value-resolver-reuse-for-multiple-types)

Answer (score 1):

There is complete guide on how to use dotnet core DI in automapper.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/v12.0.1/Dependency-injection.html

Sample code is given below:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/TestApp/Program.cs